# Metric matrix of lower rank

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry

I am studying a particular Riemannian metric, and I have a coordinate description of this metric in coordinates $(u,v,a,b)$. Explicitly, the metric is given by:

[image]

When I write the metric as a matrix in the basis $(du,dv,da,db)$, I find that it is a rank 2 matrix. Indeed, it's diagonalisable to a matrix of the form $$ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
\alpha & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \beta &0 &0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{array} \right) $$

What does this mean for the metric I started with? Is this a metric for a two-dimensional manifold? Is there some change of variables so that the metric is manifestly two-dimensional?

Comment: Unless you are using very unconventional definitions, it means that you have made a calculation error. A Riemannian metric is non-degenerate and so must be represented by a non-singular matrix.

Comment: I think I am in the situation where I am using too many coordinates to represent my Riemannian manifold. Consider, as an example, the metric $ds^2 = dx^2 + 2dx dy + dy^2$ is represented by a singular matrix, and so doesn't correspond to an honest two dimensional metric. We do a change of variables, and let $u = x+y$. Then the induced metric is simply $ds^2 = du^2$, which is an honest flat metric on a one-dimensional space, the line parameterised by the coordinate $u$. In the original coordinates, the coordinate $u$ parameterises lines $x+y=constant$, which is a one-dimensional foliation of R2.

Comment: The induced metric on what? The substitution $u = x + y$ is not a change of variables. The quadratic form described by $dx^2 + 2dxdy + dy^2$ has as radical the line $\operatorname{span} {(1,-1)}$. This means that if you restrict the quadratic form to any one-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ whose tangent line is never parallel to $(1,-1)$, you'll get a honest to god metric which will be flat (as all one-dimensional metrics are). If you restrict $ds^2$ to the lines $x + y = c$, you'll get zero.

Comment: If you consider the coordinate $v = x - y$ then $(u,v)$ is an orthogonal coordinate system on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and your metric can be expressed as $ds^2 = 1(du)^2 + 0(dv)^2$ which shows that if you restrict it to the lines $v = c$ (where $dv = 0$), you'll get the metric $du^2$. In this sense, you can think of $ds^2 = du^2$ as a family of one-dimensional Riemannian metrics that are defined on the submanifolds $v = c$ which foliate $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: In your case, if you can find a change of coordinates $(u',v',a',b')$ in which the quadratic form is expressed as $\alpha du'^2 + \beta dv'^2$ with $\alpha,\beta$ constant (this is much stronger than saying that the matrix is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\alpha,\beta$) then similarly, your quadratic form will restrict to a flat metric on the submanifolds $a' = \text{const}, b' = \text{const}$.

Comment: Do the coefficients need to be constant? If I found a change of variables such that the quadratic form was expressed as $\alpha du'^2 + \beta dv'^2 + 2\gamma du'dv'$, where $\alpha, \beta$ and $\gamma$ were functions of $u'$ and $v'$, is that enough to conclude that the quadratic form restricts to a (curved) metric on the submanifolds $a' = const$, $b'=const$? The problem comes from physics, and I expect to get a curved metric on a two dimensional manifold.

Comment: They don't have to be constant, but it should be a metric (so you want the matrix to be positive definite assuming you want a Riemannian metric). Also, you'll have infinitely many different (local) foliations corresponding to different choices of coordinates $a',b'$ that complete the coordinates $u',v'$ into a coordinate system (in your previous example, you could have used $v = y$ and then $ds^2 = d(u - v)^2 + 2d(u - v)dv + dv^2 = du^2 - 2dudv + dv^2 + 2dudv - 2dv^2 + dv^2 = du^2$ and so on).